# angular directive attributes are set (or not) yet present inside a setTimeout with 0 seconds

Tags: angularjs, attributes, scope, directive

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3uax/)

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
    .directive('list', function factory() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                size: '=',
                listWidth: '@'
            },
            replace: true,
            template: '<ul class="syn-list"><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li></ul>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

                $('#p1').html(scope.size + ' - ' + attrs.size + ' :: ' + scope.listWidth + ' - ' + attrs.listWidth);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#p2').html(scope.size + ' - ' + attrs.size + ' :: ' + scope.listWidth + ' - ' + attrs.listWidth);
                }, 0);
            }
        };
    });
```

Why scope.size is set to the expected value and scope.listWidth returns undefined?

And why inside a setTimeout call with 0 seconds scope.listWidth is set to the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using @ this happens 
 because during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to undefined.When you add settimeout(0) gives a pause which gives browser a chance to do the interpolation. When using = there is no interpolation you directly use $parse service avaialable in angular to use the parent scope properties so there are not undefined without setTimeout.You should not be directly using scope.value instead put a $observe property on the required attribute